# Create multiple dictionaries with respect to the elements in the list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
dl = [['Part Number', 'W501', 'W502', 'W503', 'W504', 'W505', 'W506', 'W507'],
 ['Weight (Kgs) *', 1.653, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 1.19, 0.71],
 ['Volume Month *', 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
 ['Emitter Name', 'Foo'],
 ['Emitter Location', 'Manesar'],
 ['Contact person Name', 'bar'],
 ['Designation', 'Project'],
 ['Contact Number', '123456'],]
```

How can I create `n` number of dictionaries with respect to elements in the largest list minus 1. For e.g here `n` is 7.

If the  length of the list is 2 then it's elements should be in every dictionary. The key is first element of list and the following are the values.

Expected output:

```
p1 = {'Part Number':'W501', 'Weight (Kgs) *':1.63, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', ...}
p2 = {'Part Number':'W502', 'Weight (Kgs) *':0.14, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', ...}
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look there: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you're supposed to show us what you already tried and explain where you're stuck, not asking peoples here to kinda "do your homework"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with list and dict comprehension to make something like this:

```py
dl = [['Part Number', 'W501', 'W502', 'W503', 'W504', 'W505', 'W506', 'W507'],
 ['Weight (Kgs) *', 1.653, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 1.19, 0.71],
 ['Volume Month *', 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
 ['Emitter Name', 'Foo'],
 ['Emitter Location', 'Manesar'],
 ['Contact person Name', 'bar'],
 ['Designation', 'Project'],
 ['Contact Number', '123456']]

n = max(len(value) for value in dl)

every_dict = {value[0]: value[1] for value in dl if len(value) == 2}

specific_dict = [{value[0]: value[i] for value in dl if len(value) == n} for i in range(1, n)]

combined_dict = [{**specific, **every_dict} for specific in specific_dict]
```

Output:

```py
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(combined_dict, indent=2))
[
  {
    "Part Number": "W501",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 1.653,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W502",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 0.14,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W503",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 0.1,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W504",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 0.11,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W505",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 0.11,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W506",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 1.19,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  },
  {
    "Part Number": "W507",
    "Weight (Kgs) *": 0.71,
    "Volume Month *": 2000,
    "Emitter Name": "Foo",
    "Emitter Location": "Manesar",
    "Contact person Name": "bar",
    "Designation": "Project",
    "Contact Number": "123456"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's not the most flexible solution to changes in the initial list. But under the conditions proposed in the question it works

```
dl = [['Part Number', 'W501', 'W502', 'W503', 'W504', 'W505', 'W506', 'W507'],
 ['Weight (Kgs) *', 1.653, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 1.19, 0.71],
 ['Volume Month *', 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
 ['Emitter Name', 'Foo'],
 ['Emitter Location', 'Manesar'],
 ['Contact person Name', 'bar'],
 ['Designation', 'Project'],
 ['Contact Number', '123456']]
 
listofprod = zip(dl)

final = []
for index, item in enumerate(dl[0][1:]):
    productdict = {}
    for param in dl:
        if len(param[1:]) > index:
            productdict[f"{param[0]}"] = param[index + 1]
        else:
            productdict[f"{param[0]}"] = param[-1]
    final.append(productdict)
    
for el in final:
    print(el)
```

Output:

```
{'Part Number': 'W501', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 1.653, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W502', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.14, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W503', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.1, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W504', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.11, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W505', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.11, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W506', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 1.19, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
{'Part Number': 'W507', 'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.71, 'Volume Month *': 2000, 'Emitter Name': 'Foo', 'Emitter Location': 'Manesar', 'Contact person Name': 'bar', 'Designation': 'Project', 'Contact Number': '123456'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension solution:

```
rest_dict = {dll[0]:dll[1] for dll in dl[3:]}
pair_list = [[{ls[0]: lss} for lss in ls[1:]] for ls in dl[:3]]
flatten_dl = [{**p, **w, **v, **rest_dict} for p, w, v in list(zip(*pair_list))]
```

The result:

```
print(flatten_dl)
[{'Part Number': 'W501',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 1.653,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W502',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.14,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W503',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.1,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W504',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.11,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W505',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.11,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W506',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 1.19,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'},
 {'Part Number': 'W507',
  'Weight (Kgs) *': 0.71,
  'Volume Month *': 2000,
  'Emitter Name': 'Foo',
  'Emitter Location': 'Manesar',
  'Contact person Name': 'bar',
  'Designation': 'Project',
  'Contact Number': '123456'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dl = [
    ['Part Number', 'W501', 'W502', 'W503', 'W504', 'W505', 'W506', 'W507'],
    ['Weight (Kgs) *', 1.653, 0.14, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 1.19, 0.71],
    ['Volume Month *', 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
    ['Emitter Name', 'Foo'],
    ['Emitter Location', 'Manesar'],
    ['Contact person Name', 'bar'],
    ['Designation', 'Project'],
    ['Contact Number', '123456']
]

def even_the_list(arr):
    getmaxlen=lambda arr:max(len(i) for i in arr)
    maxlen=getmaxlen(arr)
    for idx,i in enumerate(arr):
        if len(i)!=maxlen:
            x=[i[1] for j in range(maxlen-1)]
            x.insert(0,i[0])
            arr.remove(i)
            arr.insert(idx,x)
    return arr
dl=even_the_list(dl)
x=list(zip(*dl))
print(*x,sep='\n')
```